# VirtualBox VM guest to pop up a window to the host machine

Tags: popup, debian, virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox

**Question mark**
I'm wondering whether it's possible for the VM guest machine to pop up a window to the MS-Windows host machine once a task is done within the VM (not an email). If I'm not dreaming, how to  achieve that ?

**Why**
The VM is a simulator for a production server. Code is written within the host IDE and tested straight into the VM. So files are transferred manually from the IDE to the VM, and then automatically moved, formatted, chmoded, chowned and so on in the VM. This process can take a while, so I want to warn the devleopper once the process is over. The developper have no access to the VM and shall not necessary have one.

**Config**
Tool: VirtualBox 4.1
host: MS-Windows XP or Windows seven
guest: VM Debian
shared dir: yes
network : bridged connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this ability existed, it would be quite a security hole in VirtualBox. Guest VMs gaining access to the host machine's OS is not a good thing! As such, I don't think it's possible to accomplish this in a supported manner.

Instead, think of it as two separate machines. What mechanisms do you have for causing alerts or popups on one machine from another? Is anything like IMs, netsend, etc enabled in your environment?

Comment: Yeah, agreed. I have no IM or such stuffs. Maybe I will try netcat or similar. That's only for the development stage, not for production obviously. Thx.